# Elasticsearch how to join publications and keywords

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, parent-child, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have defined two indexes in elasticsearch that are populated with two different queries coming from a postgres database. I have many hundred of documents with thousand of keywords, and I have used logstash to populate the two indexes.

The first index is called `publication` and is defined as follow:

```
"mappings" : {
  "doc" : {
    "properties" : {
      "external_id" : {"type": "text" },
      "title" : {"type": "text", "analyzer":"english" },
      "description" : { "type" : "text", "analyzer":"english" }
    }
  }
}
```

The second index is called `keyword` and is defined as follow:

```
"mappings" : {
   "doc" : {
      "properties" : {
         "publication_id" : {"type": "keyword" },
         "keyword" :  {"type": "keyword" }
      }
   }
}
```

The relationship between the two indexes is based on the `external_id` <-> `publication_id`.

I am trying to define other indexes in a way that I can locate all the `publications` that have a specific `keyword` or all the `keywords` that are defined for a specific `publication`

Comment: Do you want to find all `publication` documents only having the `publication_id` of a `keyword` document?

Comment: Not exactly. I would like to search for a keyword and have the list of all publications details of those that contains the searched keyword.

Comment: Thanks :) In this case, which version of ES are you using?

Comment: The version is 6.3.1

Comment: In this case, you won't be able to use parent-child relationship if you keep these documents in different indices. It's only possible if they are in the same index. You could use a [terms query with terms lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup), but to achieve this you would have to know the `keyword` document id before.